# An object extends its companion case class in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

As an example, in the Play framework,

You see a case class JsPath and its companion object defined as follows inside the package play.api.libs.json

```
case class JsPath(path: List[PathNode] = immutable.this.Nil) extends Product with Serializable

object JsPath extends JsPath
```

In general, what benefits do you get when you extend an object with its companion case class?

Comment: Arrived here because of sealed abstract class GetCurrentCount; case object GetCurrentCount extends GetCurrentCount; in akka fault tolerance sample: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fault-tolerance-sample.html#full-source-code-of-the-fault-tolerance-sample

Answer (score 2):

There is no benefit except for some confusion and that you can use the `JsPath` object as empty `JsPath`. If you need an empty object, it is probably more readable if you give it a separate name (equivalent to `List`'s `Nil`):

```
object EmptyJsPath extends JsPath(Nil)
```

or you define a `empty` method on the companion (like most other collection classes do):

```
object JsPath {
  def empty = ...
}
```

Comment: But is there any benefit in general?

Comment: @platypus You mean like something that happens "automatically" like `apply` and `unapply` on the companion when you define a case class?

Comment: I meant that if you see this pattern in general (not in Play-specific context) when an object extends its companion case class, why do people do that? Are there some benefits that's universally known?

Comment: @platypus Oh... to be honest, I have never seen that before. There is no built-in magic associated with it, but depending on your exact semantics, it could maybe make sense.